# Is it possible to use iCloud to share key-value storage across multiple apps without the primary app installed?

Tags: icloud

I have a series of unrelated apps that I want to share a login session across, and iCloud seems to provide the perfect solution for that.

I'm using OAuth, and I would love to share the token across multiple apps using the ideas talked about in [Configuring Common Key-Value Storage for Multiple Apps](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/Chapters/iCloudFundametals.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012094-CH6-SW1).

The only limitation I see is that a 'primary app' needs to be identified, and, of my apps, I don't have one that can be identified as 'primary'.  Indeed, my users may only install one of my apps in the series (which may not be the 'primary' app) but I still want to allow the token to be accessible from a central location.

Is it possible to share the token in this way without the user having bought/installed the 'primary' app?